# how to disable enter key in gridview in edit mode in c# while using imagebutton

Tags: c#, asp.net

On one button click I am displaying this `gridview`, problem is that when I am entering

`Enter` while gridview is in editmode, it is updating 1st row of gridview..I know

how to disable enter for whole page but not getting how to do it for `image button`.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                  DataKeyNames="st_id"  OnRowEditing="EditRecord"

                OnRowCancelingEdit="CancelRecord" OnRowUpdating="UpdateRecord" 
                       CellPadding="4" EnableModelValidation="True" ForeColor="Black" 
                       GridLines="Vertical" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#DEDFDE" 
                       BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px">
                       <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:CommandField EditImageUrl="~/Styles/image/Icon-edit-22x22.png" ShowEditButton="true" 
                            ButtonType="Image"  CancelImageUrl="~/Styles/image/cancel.png" 
                            UpdateImageUrl="~/Styles/image/update.png" CausesValidation="true"  ValidationGroup="bottom" />
                       ------
```

Answer (score 1):

> A simple `jquery` function will do the trick for you.

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#GridView1").keydown(function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                return false;
            }
        });

    });

</script>
```